# Gulp inline changing case of HTML markup

Tags: html, css, gulp

I have a Gulp task to inline CSS and JS into my HTML file:

```
gulp.task('html', function () {
    gulp.src(source + '**/*.+(html|php)')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.inline({
        base: source,
        disabledTypes: ['svg', 'img']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(build))
    .pipe(reload({
        stream: true
    }));
});
```

I'm finding that the inline plugin is making changes to my HTML markup.
Most noticeably it is changing the case of attributes.

`mktoName="Banner Heading"` becomes `mktoname="Banner Heading"`

Is there a fix for this?

I tried adding `html` to the `disabledType` options, but this did nothing.

Thanks

Comment: I hesitate to say this, but `mktoname` is not HTML.

Comment: I think the best approach is to not use camel case (or any uppercase) in your html. Can you change it to `mkto-name` for your custom attribute?

Comment: The attribute that is being changes is a marketo specific tag for marketo guided templates. I cannot change this name or casing.

Answer (score 0):

A work around for the time being is to pipe a replace after the inline.

```
.pipe($.replace('mktoname','mktoName'))
```